# MySql UNION with different columns applying default value?

Tags: php, mysql, join, union

Is it possible querying two similair mysql tables at one request, setting the not matching columns to a default value like NULL?

```
table1
col1 col2 col3
A    B    C

table2 
col1 col2 col4
D    E    F
```

result should be:

```
table
col1 col2 col3 col4
A    B    C    NULL
D    E    NULL F
```

Comment: Do you know in advance the non matching column names and are ther few enough to care write them by hand as the answer below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's quite possible:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, NULL as col4
  FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2, NULL, col4
  FROM table2
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/978491/1).